# how to save String values as one array in android

Tags: java, android

I am getting the keyss from the firebase database as :

```
                promoCodeKey = history.getKey();
```

it is giving me output as T20  Test10 etc as string

I want to save it in an array to check from the editText if the user enters any text and if the text matches any of the key

How can i achieve this?

I want to check from each key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use String split function.

```
String keysString = history.getKey();

//removes all "Key promo is" text
String replaceString=keysString.replace("Key promo is","");   
// removes all white spaces
String trimString = replaceString.replaceAll("\\s+",""); 

String[] keys = trimString.split(".");
for (int i = 0; i < keys.lenght; i++) {
    if (keys[i] == editText.getText()) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot add the values manually. i have to take it from the database because it will change accordingly. And i dont want to split it. I want to check from each key if it matches the text in the EditText that user enters @Ban Markovic

Comment: Does your function "history.getKey()" returns string which is formatted like "T20 Test10"?

Comment: You can than split it into String array. And than with for loop iterate through every key and check if it matches the EditText input? I updated my response, please check.

Comment: can you please give me an example for this because iam adding it to array and it is giving me separate arrays as [T20] . [TEST10] . etc

Comment: Can you copy the exact result which history.getKey() returns?

Comment: Key promo isT20 .           Key promo isT30 .   this is when iam taking it as String           Key promo is array[T20]       Key promo is array[T30] this is when im tring to add it to array . the code for array is     promoCodeKey = history.getKey();
                    ArrayList<String> priceList = new ArrayList();
                    priceList.add(promoCodeKey);

Comment: Hi, I cleaned now your string. So this code removes unnecessary text, and than removes white space, which leaves "." as separator between key elements.

Comment: It is still giving the same result as [T20] separately

Comment: I thought you need to separate them, so you can check for each if it matches user input?